Unable to choose alternative workflows within DSpace.7.x
I wanted to have multiple reviewers review a submitted item. I am trying to enable an alternative workflow built into DSpace7 that supports this, so I activated the 'scoredReview' workflow. In the file dspace/config/spring/api/workflow.xml, I have added a new entry with a key and value-ref with a community handle.
    <bean class="org.dspace.xmlworkflow.XmlWorkflowFactoryImpl">
    <property name="workflowMapping">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="defaultWorkflow"
                   value-ref="defaultWorkflow"/>
            <entry key="123456789/1" value-ref="scoreReview"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    </bean>

I restarted the docker container. When the submitter deposits an item, it moves on to a pool and only one reviewer can 'claim' that item for review.  This is the default workflow behaviour.  How will I know that scoreReview is enabled? How do multiple reviewers be assigned to review a workflow item?
